# Parsing data from an rss feed using python to a CSV display issue for salary field

Tags: python

I have written a script that takes job data from an RSS feed and adds it into a CSV file, this works great! However, I came across an issue with how salary data was displaying. The below shows how the data is appended to the data list:

```
# Append the entry data to the feed_data list
feed_data.append(
    [
        title,
        published_date,
        summary,
        location,
        application_email,
        company,
        company_website,
        salary_from + " to " + salary_to,
    ]
)
```

The line `salary_from + " to " + salary_to` will show a salary range, for example 35000 to 45000. However, it was actually displaying by adding 4 after the decimal point, e.g. 35000.0000 to 45000.0000.

To get around this I altered to the following:

```
salary_from[:-5] + " to " + salary_to[:-5]
```

This worked a treat and displayed as 35000 to 45000. Super! That was until I realised there are certain salaries that had a 0 value. This then caused the output to display as "to".

To try and fix this I added an if else:

```
salary_from[:-5] + " to " + salary_to[:-5]
if salary_from == 0
else "Unknown",
```

However, this would then lead to every single Salary field within the CSV file displaying as "Unknown" regardless of if it had a salary or not.

What I'm trying to achieve is just those that have a 0 value displaying as "Unknown" and those with a value displaying with the correct salary range. Thank you for any help!

Comment: `salary_from` and `salary_to` appear to be strings rather than numbers, so `salary_from == 0` is always false

Comment: _This then caused the output to display as "to"_ ...sounds like the value was empty string rather than 0. I think the logic is backwards, try `salary_from[:-5] + " to " + salary_to[:-5] if salary_from else "Unknown"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An f-string is helpful. (Note the leading f before the string.)

```py
if salary_from == "0":
    salary_range = "Unknown"
else:
    salary_range = f"{float(salary_from):.0f} to {float(salary_to):.0f}"

feed_data.append(
    [
        ...
        company_website,
        salary_range,
    ]
)
```

The `:.0f` formats it with 0 decimals.